# Tablesorter plugin custom filter function not working and giving wrong filtered result

Tags: tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter 2.23.4 plugin and for one of the column i have added custom code for filter_functions widget option but it seems it is not working :(
any help will be really grateful.

my code is as below :

```
filter_functions: {
                    10: function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
                        return 
   /f/i.test($r.children().eq(i).children().eq(0).text());
                    }
                }
```

Last column of my table is having data as a link upon click of which a popup is opening to update the value (popup content are also within the cell) so i added one hidden span on top in the cell for which i am doing comparison and returning true or false as above. while filtering it is not giving matched rows.

I removed the filter_function and added text_filter as :

```
textExtraction: {
                10: function (node, table) {
                    // this is how it is done by default
                    return $(node).children().eq(0).text() ||
                        node.innerText ||
                        $(node).text() ||
                        '';
                }
            },
```

and it worked. :)

Comment: Can you please modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/) with some example data and the filter function you are using. Just a sample of a few rows and columns should do (no need for all 11 columns).

Comment: Thanks mottie your sample fiddle helped me and it fixed the issue as i tried by updating your sample in my grid format and it was working perfectly in the sample then I checked the properties and then instead of filter_functions I set the property text_extraction and it worked for me.

Comment: and one more thing i notice with 2.23.4 version; it missed the fix for sticky header issue which was not working with hide_filter as true for which you added a fix in version 2.16.3.
same i applied in the latest js code and it worked.